# How do you access multiple mixins via reflection in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Here's the simplest example.

```
class MixA{
}

class MixB{
}

class Base{
}

class MyClass extends Base with MixA, MixB{
}

main(){
  var m = new MyClass();
  reflect(m).superclass.mixin; //This only gives MixB. Is there a way to get a list of all the mixins?
}
```

I can't find a way to just get a list of all the mixins that were applied to `MyClass`

Answer (score 1):

Each mixin application creates a new subclass:

```
void main(){
  final m = new MyClass();
  final r = reflect(m);
  print(r.type.superclass.mixin);
  print(r.type.superclass.superclass.mixin);
}
```